# Function works withouth curly braces and doesn't work with them, why?

Tags: javascript, math, functional-programming, brackets, curly-braces

I'm doing FreeCode camp exercises, and this has messed-up my mind:

```
const squareList = arr =>
  arr
    .filter(num => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0)
    .map(num => Math.pow(num, 2));

const squaredIntegers = squareList([4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

This works correctly, but if i put:

```
 const squareList = arr => {
      arr
        .filter(num => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0)
        .map(num => Math.pow(num, 2));
    }
    const squaredIntegers = squareList([4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]);

    console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

The typical curly brackets which are used normally in many functions, it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is a set of `statements` (with curly braces) and other is an `expression`

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } // needs to return something
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }
```

So when you are using the first form ,you need to `return` something from it

So in your non working case it should be a `return` statement

```
const squareList = arr => {
     return arr
        .filter(num => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0)
        .map(num => Math.pow(num, 2));
    }
```

> Any unit of code that can be evaluated to a value is an **expression**.
>
> A **statement** is an instruction or set of instructions to perform a
>   specific action

A more detailed explanation is here in [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2):

Without the curly brackets, `return` is added for you.

With the curly brackets, you need to add it yourself.

---

```
const squareList = arr => {
    return arr
        .filter(num => num > 0 && num % parseInt(num) === 0)
        .map(num => Math.pow(num, 2));
}
const squaredIntegers = squareList([4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For better or for worse, javascript allows arrow functions to be either of the form

```
args => expression
```

or

```
args => function_body
```

So they "straddle the line" between old-school Javascript closures (`function (arglist...) {...}`) which must have a function body, and lambdas in more purely functional languages where they would always take an expression.

The working example you have is of the form `args => expression`, but if you put curly-braces around the expression, it is interpreted as `args => function_body`.  But a function body with no return statement returns `undefined`.  This is easy to fix by adding the `return` keyword, since `args => expression` is really a shorthand for a function that *returns* what the expression evaluates to.

```
args => {return expression}
```

Note that this syntactic ambiguity also can lead to problems if you want an arrow function to whose `expression` should be an object literal; in that case you have to say

```
args => ({
    // object key/value pairs
})
```

(note the extra () which prevent the compiler from thinking you're providing a function body).